# 16 bit artimatic sum in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bit, bitstring

I am working on a program that is creating IRIG106 Chapter 10 data for a cube-sat project. Currently it is being implemented in python and I am having difficulty implementing the final component of the Chapter 10 header.

The way I have implemented it I am currently finding checksum values that are larger than what will fit inside of an integer of the size defined by the specification (2 bytes).

The standard defines the header checksum in section 10.6.1.1 paragraph "J" of the [IRIG 106-09 standard](http://irig106.org/docs/106-09/chapter10.pdf). It is defined as the following:

**J Header Checksum. (2 Bytes) contains a value representing a 16-bit arithmetic sum of all 16-bit words in the header excluding the Header Checksum Word.**

There is also a [programming manual](http://irig106.org/docs/123-09/IRIG_106-07_Chapter_10_Programming_Handbook.pdf) provided that has example C code that shows the following (from page A-2-17):

```c
uint16_t I106_CALL_DECL uCalcHeaderChecksum(SuI106Ch10Header * psuHeader)
{
    int iHdrIdx;
    uint16_t uHdrSum;
    uint16_t * aHdr = (uint16_t *)psuHeader;

    uHdrSum = 0;
    for (iHdrIdx=0; iHdrIdx<(HEADER_SIZE-2)/2; iHdrIdx++)
        uHdrSum += aHdr[iHdrIdx];

    return uHdrSum;
}
```

I have implemented the following in Python using the [BitString library](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/):

```python
def calculate_checksum(byte_data: BitArray = None, header_length_bytes: int = 24, chunk_length: int = 16): 

    # Set the checksum to zero:
    checksum = 0

    # Loop through the Chapter 10 header and compute the 16 bit arithmetic sum:
    for bit_location in range(0, (header_length_bytes-2), chunk_length):

        # Get the range of bits to select:
        bit_range = slice(bit_location, (bit_location + chunk_length))

        # Get the uint representation of the bit data found: 
        checksum += Bits(bin=byte_data.bin[bit_range]).uint

    # Write the computed checksum as binary data to the start location of the checksum in the header: 
    byte_data.overwrite(Bits(uint=checksum, length=chunk_length), (header_length_bytes-2*8))
```

Any thoughts or insights you could provide would be extremely appreciated. I know it should be a simple solution but I am just not able to see it.

--- Update 2 ---
I tried doing both roll over and truncation and they both produced the same result:

```python
test_value = 2**16
test_value1 = test_value + 500
test_value2 = test_value1 % (2**16) -> 500
test_value3 = test_value1 & 0xFFFF -> 500
```

--- Update 3 ---

When I compare the execution of the python and C checksum functions I have run into the following using these values as an input per the spec:

```
Sync = "EB25" (2 bytes)
ChannelID = 1 (2 bytes)
PacketLen = 1024 (4 bytes)
```

When I compare the outputs at each step I see the following:

C:

```
Header0: EB25                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 index =  0 16bit chunk = 60197 checksum = 60197                                                                                                                                                                            
Header1: 0001                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 index =  1 16bit chunk =     1 checksum = 60198                                                                                                                                                                            
Header2: 0400                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 index =  2 16bit chunk =  1024 checksum = 61222                                                                                                                                                                            
Header3: 0000                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 index =  3 16bit chunk =     0 checksum = 61222
```

Python:

```
eb25
index:  0 chunk: 60197 checksum: 60197
0001
index:  1 chunk:     1 checksum: 60198
0000
index:  2 chunk:     0 checksum: 60198
0400
index:  3 chunk:  1024 checksum: 61222
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing up bits and bytes in your code: it seems unlikely that a header that's only 24 *bits* long could usefully contain a 16-bit checksum...  To truncate the sum to 16 bits, use `checksum & 0xFFFF`.

Comment: @jasonharper yes the header length itself is 24 bytes long, I am just not sure from the provided math if the correct method is to truncate it as you say or should it roll over?

Comment: Have you tried taking the checksum of the same string using both of these, and see if they are the same?

Comment: @KennyOstrom I did just try it and the both come up with the same result if I roll over ```(checksum = checksum % (2**chunk_length)``` or if I truncate them ```checksum = checksum & 0xFFFF``` The other option I found out about was bit wise addition with bit carry over but this doesn't seem like what should be done in this case.

Comment: So you're good now, right?

Comment: I just added an update 3 that shows some weird behavior once I hit 32bit (4 byte) parts of the header. while it gets to the same number I am worried about why it is being encoded the way it is as my understanding is a 32 bit int would have the byte position of 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 which is how the python represents it by the C appears to be grabbing it in 3,2,1,0,7,6,5,4 which makes no sense to me. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, I know this question is really old, but I had the same issue. The endianess of the packet matters. In a `.ch10` file, the packet start is `0x25EB` because each section is little endian. Here's how I'm doing everything right now in C-ish code.

```
// read until the end of the file
while (!atEndOfFile)
{
    // verify that we get teh sync packet
    if ( readNextByte == 0x25 )
    {
       if ( readNextByte == 0xEB )
       {
          // store the sync packet
          byte packetHeader[24];
          packetHeader[0] = 0x25;
          packetHeader[1] = 0xEB
          
          // grab the rest of the header
          for ( int i = 2; i < 24; j++ )
          {
              packetHeader[j] = readNextByte;
          }
          
          // grab the check sum from the packet
          uint16 actualCheckSum = (packetHeader[23] << 8) | 
                                  packetHeader[22];
          
          // calculate the checkSum
          uint16 calculatedCheckSum = 0;
          for ( int i = 0; i < 22; i += 2 )
          {
              calculatedCheckSum  += (packetHeader[i + 1] << 8) |
                                      packetHeader[i];
          }
          
          // verify the calculation
          if ( calculatedCheckSum == actualChecksum )
          {
              printLine( "We calculated the checksum!");
              printLine( "actual checksum: " + actualCheckSum +
                         "calculated checksum" + calculatedCheckSum );
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I haven't done enough digging into the irig106 library, but I believe that it handles the translation when it reads in a `.ch10` file.